# What part of the energy applied to accelerate electrons radiate and why?

Tags: acceleration, radiation, antennas

I understand that accelerated electrons will emit radiations, for example in a cyclotron or antenna. However I dont understand why some energy will sort of stay in the electrons and accelerate them, while some energy will dissipate as EM radiation. How does the distribution occur? Are there factors favoring one over the other? For example, is it possible to accelerate an electron and actually make it keep unchanged its velocity while transducing the entire amount of acceleration to radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electromagnetic radiation by a charged particle depends on its acceleration. This radiation carries away some of the particle’s energy, momentum, and angular momentum. Whatever is not radiated away is kept.

There are formulas for the rate of energy loss, etc. For example, in CGS units the power radiated by a point charge of mass $m$ and charge $q$ is

$$P=-\frac{2}{3}\frac{q^2}{m^2c^3}\frac{dp_\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau}$$

where $p^\mu$ is the four-momentum and $\tau$ the proper time along the particle’s worldline.

Comment: I am not sure your answer brings anything new here. Do you mean that the proportion of energy dissipated as radiation is entirely determined by the amount of incoming energy?

Comment: The relation between the energy absorbed by the particle and the energy radiated by the particle depends on the details of how the particle is being accelerated. There is not a simple proportionality.

Comment: Here is a link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synchrotron.html

Comment: It is worth noting that when a magnetic field keeps charged particles moving in a circle at constant speed, they are accelerating because their velocity is changing direction. They radiate energy even though the magnetic field is not adding *any* energy to them. In order to keep them from slowing down in a cyclotron, an electric field adds energy to them to make up the radiative loss. The electric field also gets them moving fast in the first place.

Comment: @G. Smith: you said « the energy radiated by the particle depends on the details of how the particle is being accelerated », but you realize this is what I am asking here right? Thanks for completing your answer by the way.

Comment: What you actually asked seemed extremely unclear to me, so I should have voted to close, or requested clarification in a comment, rather than trying to guess what your confusion was. Sorry.